# How to map Java overloaded constructors to Frege functions

Tags: java, frege

Java (unfortunately) supports constructors and methods overload. For example, the [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) has four constructors. In Frege I can't do:

```hs
data Map = native java.util.Map

data HashMap = native java.util.HashMap where
    native new :: () -> STMutable s HashMap
    native new :: Int -> STMutable s HashMap
    native new :: Int -> Float -> STMutable s HashMap
    native new :: Mutable s Map -> STMutable s HashMap
```

This doesn't compile because I can't bind four times "new". Is it possible to have four "Java constructors" in a Frege datatype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overloaded constructors and methods can be defined using `|`:

```
data HashMap k v = native java.util.HashMap where

  native new :: Mutable s (Map k v) -> STMutable s (HashMap k v)
              | () -> STMutable s (HashMap k v)
              | Int -> STMutable s (HashMap k v)
              | Int -> Float -> STMutable s (HashMap k v)
```

You can also use this https://github.com/Frege/native-gen as the starting point to generate Frege code from Java class. The above code is generated using that project.

I said starting point because this cannot be completely automated. We can't determine the purity of a method and nulls from native methods. Hence you can take the generated code and modify the purity or make the return type `Maybe a` if you know that the method may return `null`.

Comment: @mariop Note however, that because of currying, the Frege compiler has a more difficult job to find out which variant is meant: Like in this example `HashMap.new 42` could be attributed the type `STMutable s (HashMap k v)` and `Float -> STMutable s (HashMap k v)`.  This is normally not a problem in otherwise type correct do-blocks, but in other contexts you may need to give the result type explicitly to disambiguate.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, you can also write:

```
data HashMap = native java.util.HashMap where
    native new       :: () -> STMutable s HashMap
    native new1  new :: Int -> STMutable s HashMap
    native new2  new :: Int -> Float -> STMutable s HashMap
    native new3  new :: Mutable s Map -> STMutable s HashMap
```

i.e. in the general form, you give a name you want to use in Frege, and then the java name.

This is also indispensable when the item you want to access in the java code has a name that is a keyword in Frege, like `data`. For example:

```
    native datum "data" :: Int
```